# Word 2016 template with jump stops

Tags: microsoft-word, autohotkey, templates

When making a template which includes the same text except for a few distinct additions that I need to insert, how can I include "jump stops" to signal the cursor to each desired place?

I believe Word 97 would allow this. If I'm not mistaken the command was <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. All I had to do was make a template (auto text/correct) and insert ?? for information I needed to add. Then I could <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and "jump" from ?? field to ?? field throughout the document. Is it possible to make this happen with Word 2016? I have Office 365 and Word 2016.

Answer (score 1):

F11 is used to go forward to the next field. Shift+F11 goes to previous field.

I am on a Mac keyboard and the same keyboard shortcuts work, but I have to add the Command Key into the sequence. (Cmd+F11, or Cmd+Shift+F11)

Per your comment and my follow-up below, here is more information about Fields in Word...

They are placeholders for adding dynamic data into Word documents. in the Windows version of Word 2016 you access them from the Quick Parts button in the Text Group, on the Insert tab. In the Mac version of Word 2016 Quick Parts does not exist but Fields do and there is a button for Fields on the same tab and in the same ribbon group.

[image]

For your purpose, I suggest the Fill-in Field.

[image]

After selecting Fill-in you can optionally add a Prompt or leave it blank and you can optionally add the Default Response. If you want to continue to use the double question marks that you used in the past, type them in as I have in the example. Alternatively, you can wait and input the response, which you will see no matter what.

[image]

Pressing OK on the above dialog inserts, at the location of the current selection point, the Response text as a Field in your document.

With this established as a Field, you can now navigate to it using **F11** and **Shift+F11**. Being that it is a Fill-in type Field, when the field is selected all you do is type, and the Field and it current text (? ? in this example) are replaced.

I hope this helps

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for that info.  And how do I set the field in the template that I create so that F11 will go from field to field?  As I said, in earlier version I used ??.  Is there a special character that I have to use for F11 to "identify" it?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You used the term "field" and I thought you understood Word Fields. I will add a bit more explanation to my answer.